# Flutter read from and write to rtf file

Tags: flutter, dart, rtf

I discovered Flutter for desktop applications recently. Now I want to make an application that is able to extract RichText from and write it to rtf files.

I there any possibility to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't read rtf file from asset.
I have do some research but found nothing. Flutter has nothing to read .rtf file.

it shows response like this.

```html
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf2513
\cocoatextscaling0\cocoaplatform0{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 ArialMT;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red83\green83\blue83;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;\cssrgb\c40000\c40000\c40000;\cssrgb\c100000\c100000\c100000;}
{\*\listtable{\list\listtemplateid1\listhybrid{\listlevel\levelnfc23\levelnfcn23\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace360\levelindent0{\*\levelmarker \{disc\}}{\leveltext\leveltemplateid1\'01\uc0\u8226 ;}{\levelnumbers;}\fi-360\li720\lin720 }{\listname ;}\listid1}
{\list\listtemplateid2\listhybrid{\listlevel\levelnfc0\levelnfcn0\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace360\levelindent0{\*\levelmarker \{decimal\}.}{\leveltext\leveltemplateid101\'02\'00.;}{\levelnumbers\'01;}\fi-360\li720\lin720 }{\listname ;}\listid2}}
{\*\listoverridetable{\listoverride\listid1\listoverridecount0\ls1}{\listoverride\listid2\listoverridecount0\ls2}}
\paperw12240\paperh15840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww11520\viewh8400\viewkind0
\deftab720
\pard\pardeftab720\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs36 \cf2 \cb3 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
1:1 Minecraft recreation of ALIEN ISOLATION\'a0You're traveling to Sevastopol Space Station, searching for information about your missing Mother. An devastating incident, however, caused caos ond anarchy at that commercial outpost of Seegson corporation.As Amanda Ripley, you're trying to get information, survive the situation and ultimately escape the station.\
\
\pard\pardeftab720\partightenfactor0
\cf2 \outl0\strokewidth0 This map is the result of more than 2500 hours of work.\'a0You're playing the protagonist of this adventure RPG, traveling through different facilities, facing different opponents, simple riddles and NPCs.\
\
\pard\pardeftab720\sl576\sa360\partightenfactor0
\cf2 THE MAP:\
\pard\tx220\tx720\pardeftab720\li720\fi-720\partightenfactor0
\ls1\ilvl0\cf2 \kerning1\expnd0\expndtw0 \outl0\strokewidth0 {\listtext \uc0\u8226  }\expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
\outl0\strokewidth0 \strokec2 Storydriven adventure RPG\cb1 \
\ls1\ilvl0\cb3 \kerning1\expnd0\expndtw0 \outl0\strokewidth0 {\listtext \uc0\u8226  }\expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
\outl0\strokewidth0 \strokec2 Singleplayer\cb1 \
\ls1\ilvl0\cb3 \kerning1\expnd0\expndtw0 \outl0\strokewidth0 {\listtext \uc0\u8226  }\expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
\outl0\strokewidth0 \strokec2 Custom resources (16x16)\cb1 \
\ls1\ilvl0\cb3 \kerning1\expnd0\expndtw0 \outl0\strokewidth0 {\listtext \uc0\u8226  }\expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
\outl0\strokewidth0 \strokec2 Custom crafting system & unique items\cb1 \
\ls1\ilvl0\cb3 \kerning1\expnd0\expndtw0 \outl0\strokewidth0 {\listtext \uc0\u8226  }\expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
\outl0\strokewidth0 \strokec2 Unique Alien Add-On\cb1 \
\pard\tx220\tx720\pardeftab720\li720\fi-720\partightenfactor0
\ls2\ilvl0\cf2 \outl0\strokewidth0 \
}
```

Comment: i done reading .rtf files from internal storage but looking for package to view .rtf files